# GDAL not available in MODIS R package?

Tags: gdal, r, error, modis, evi

I am trying to analyze the MODIS EVI 250m, 16day dataset. I found the R MODIS package and am following the instructions here: https://conservationecology.wordpress.com/2014/08/11/bulk-downloading-and-analysing-modis-data-in-r/

But when I try to run the `runGDAL` function it tells me that:

```
library(MODIS)
dates1 <- as.POSIXct( as.Date(c("01/01/2015","31/12/2015"),format = "%d/%m/%Y") )
dates2 <- transDate(dates1[1],dates1[2])
product <- "MOD13Q1"
h = "25"
v = "07"
runGdal(product=product,begin=dates2$beginDOY,end = dates2$endDOY,tileH = h,tileV = v,SDSstring = "111", outProj="4326")
```

However I get the error:

> Error in runGdal(product = product, begin = dates2$beginDOY, end = dates2$endDOY,  : 
>   GDAL not installed or configured, read in '?MODISoptions' for help

I tried using the `checkTools()` command to set GDAL:

```
MODIS:::checkTools("GDAL")
Checking availabillity of GDAL: OK, GDAL 1.11.3, released 2015/09/16 found!
```

Does anybody have any ideas on how to fix this issue?

I'm using MODIS version 0.10.33. Output of `MODISoptions()`:

```
STORAGE:
_______________
localArcPath : /Users/sujoybhattacharyya/MODIS_download
outDirPath   : /Users/sujoybhattacharyya/MODIS_download/Processed 
DOWNLOAD:
_______________
MODISserverOrder : LPDAAC, LAADS 
dlmethod         : auto 
stubbornness     : high 

PROCESSING:
_______________
GDAL           : Not available. Use 'MODIS:::checkTools('GDAL')' for more  information! 
MRT            : Not available. Use 'MODIS:::checkTools('MRT')' for more information! 
pixelSize      : asIn 
outProj        : asIn 
resamplingType : NN 
dataFormat     : GTiff 

DEPENDENCIES:
_______________
```

Comment: @SujoyBhattacharyya This is a long shot, but can you try re-installing the GDAL library in your system and/or install `rgdal` in your R library? It's not listed as a required package, but you never know...

Comment: @Phil , thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and alas nothing changed.

Comment: Thank you Aldo_Tapia for this, this helped me fix my problem when I was having trouble getting GDAL to work! I actually first had to properly install GDAL, but once I had GDAL properly installed this thread helped me get R to recognize and use GDAL.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer, so I flagged this. Please read the forum guidelines.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/113028)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the parameters of MRT and GDAL by yourself. I don't know exactly why R can't identify GDAL and MRT by default (I'm running R 3.3.1 in OS X 10.12), but I'll show you how I solve this error in my machine.

I have the same issue, this is the result of printing `MODIS::MODISoptions()`:

```
To install all required and suggested packages run:
setRepositories() # activate CRAN, R-forge, and Omegahat and then: 
install.packages(c(' ptw '),dependencies=TRUE)

sh: gdalinfo: command not found
  'MRT_HOME' not set/found! MRT is NOT enabled! See: 'https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/tools/modis_reprojection_tool'

STORAGE:
_______________
localArcPath : /Users/aldotapia/Desktop/MODIS/Insumos 
outDirPath   : /Users/aldotapia/Desktop/MODIS/Resultados 


DOWNLOAD:
_______________
MODISserverOrder : LPDAAC, LAADS 
dlmethod         : auto 
stubbornness     : high 


PROCESSING:
_______________
GDAL           : Not available. Use 'MODIS:::checkTools('GDAL')' for more information! 
MRT            : Not available. Use 'MODIS:::checkTools('MRT')' for more information! 
pixelSize      : asIn 
outProj        : asIn 
resamplingType : NN 
dataFormat     : GTiff 


DEPENDENCIES:
_______________


Warning message:
In checkGdalDriver(path = opt$gdalPath) :
  No gdal installation found please install 'gdal' on your system first!
```

Check the paths of `.Renviron`:

```
> Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin"
```

You need to add the GDAL path in this string, simply add : + gdal_path. Also, set MRT_HOME and MRT_DATA_BIN paths to `.Renviron`.

```
Sys.setenv(MRT_DATA_DIR  = "/Users/aldotapia/Desktop/MODIS/data",
           MRT_HOME = "/Users/aldotapia/Desktop/MODIS/bin",
           PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.1/Programs")
```

Now, check again `MODIS::MODISoptions()`:

```
STORAGE:
_______________
localArcPath : /Users/aldotapia/Desktop/MODIS/Insumos 
outDirPath   : /Users/aldotapia/Desktop/MODIS/Resultados 


DOWNLOAD:
_______________
MODISserverOrder : LPDAAC, LAADS 
dlmethod         : auto 
stubbornness     : high 


PROCESSING:
_______________
GDAL           : GDAL 2.1.1, released 2016/07/07 
MRT            : Enabled 
pixelSize      : asIn 
outProj        : asIn 
resamplingType : NN 
dataFormat     : GTiff 


DEPENDENCIES:
_______________
```

Hope this can help you

Comment: I have been trying your solution for a while, but I haven't had any success. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you use GDAL and MRT out of R? Maybe they aren't installed correctly

Comment: Can you elaborate? I currently have rgdal installed and when I use Sys.getenv - I get a long list of paths for different libraries.

Comment: I can post a different question if that helps? Let me know.

Comment: Use `Sys.getenv("PATH")`, check if GDAL path is in that string

Comment: I used that function and I don't see the GDAl path in the string.

Comment: Ok, this means that R doesn't know where GDAL is, so you need to add GDAL path to the string (separated with : ) and replace `PATH` with `Sys.setenv()` function