# Error in GDAL for MODIS library in R

Tags: gdal, r, modis, rgdal

An answer was provided to this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183230/gdal-not-available-in-modis-r-package) previously, however it did not solve the question.

I am analyzing MODIS data, and would like to download and process the data. Here's what I have done so far:

```
library(MODIS)

MODISoptions(localArcPath = "C:\\Users\\rameshv\\Downloads\\MODISDownloads\\",
         outDirPath = "C:\\Users\\rameshv\\Downloads\\MODISOutputs\\")


'outDirPath' does not exist and will be created in 
'C:/Users/rameshv/Downloads/MODISOutputs/'
 'MRT_HOME' not set/found! MRT is NOT enabled! See: 
 'https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/tools/modis_reprojection_tool'

 STORAGE:
  _______________
  localArcPath : C:/Users/rameshv/Downloads/MODISDownloads/ 
  outDirPath   : C:/Users/rameshv/Downloads/MODISOutputs/ 

 DOWNLOAD:
 _______________
 MODISserverOrder : LAADS, LPDAAC 
 dlmethod         : auto 
 stubbornness     : high 

 PROCESSING:
 _______________
 GDAL           : Not available. Use 'MODIS:::checkTools('GDAL')' for more information! 
 MRT            : Not available. Use 'MODIS:::checkTools('MRT')' for more information! 
 pixelSize      : asIn 
 outProj        : asIn 
 resamplingType : NN 
 dataFormat     : GTiff
```

As you notice above, it suggests that there is no GDAL. However, I have installed rgdal as well as:

```
> MODIS:::checkTools('GDAL')
 Checking availability of 'FWTools/OSGeo4W' (GDAL with HDF4 support for Windows):
  OK, 'gdalinfo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. found!
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Followed instructions provided [here](https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows) and installed GDAL again on the local machine, followed by:

```
> MODISoptions(localArcPath = 
"C:\\Users\\rameshv\\Downloads\\MODISDownloads\\",
+              outDirPath = "C:\\Users\\rameshv\\Downloads\\MODISOutputs\\")
'outDirPath' does not exist and will be created in ' 
'C:/Users/rameshv/Downloads/MODISOutputs/'
  'MRT_HOME' not set/found! MRT is NOT enabled! See: 
'https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/tools/modis_reprojection_tool'
 Detecting available write drivers!
 Found: 71 candidate drivers, detecting file extensions...
 45 usable drivers detected!

 STORAGE:
 _______________
 localArcPath : C:/Users/rameshv/Downloads/MODISDownloads/ 
 outDirPath   : C:/Users/rameshv/Downloads/MODISOutputs/ 

 DOWNLOAD:
 _______________
 MODISserverOrder : LAADS, LPDAAC 
 dlmethod         : auto 
 stubbornness     : high 

 PROCESSING:
 _______________
 GDAL           : GDAL 2.1.3, released 2017/20/01 
 MRT            : Not available. Use 'MODIS:::checkTools('MRT')' for more 
 information! 
 pixelSize      : asIn 
 outProj        : asIn 
 resamplingType : NN 
 dataFormat     : GTiff
```

Another useful Resource : https://www.ral.ucar.edu/sites/default/files/public/projects/wrf_hydro/v3_0/rwrfhydro/vignettes/modisProcessing.html