# Trouble installing GDAL in R for MODIS package

Tags: gdal, r, modis

I'm having trouble installing GDAL in R with the MODIS package. Every time run MODIS I get this error:

GDAL : Not available. Use 'MODIS:::checkTools('GDAL')' for more information!

I have tried using the link below, but the only thing it fixes is the MRT issue.
[GDAL not available in MODIS R package?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183230/gdal-not-available-in-modis-r-package)

What should I do to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows, you need your system to be properly aware of the GDAL install. If you go to Run>cmd and then type, e.g. gdalwarp at the prompt, you should see the help info for that tool.

MODIS detects GDAL properly for me. I have the OSGeo4W stack installed on this machine so I already have a lot of GDAL system variables set - any or all of these might be necessary:

```
OSGEO4W_ROOT: C:\OSGeo4W64
GDAL_DATA: %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\share\gdal
GDAL_DRIVER_PATH: %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\gdalplugins
Path: along with the rest of what's there, %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin
```

If you have standalone GDAL, GDAL_DATA will just need to point at wherever its installed, I think.

Note that every time you change these system variables, you must restart R/Rstudio before the changes will be detected.